# CMD x PowerShell do Windows no VENV

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

Estou tentando trabalho com ambientes virtuais python diretamente no terminal do PyCharm o comando ''activate'' para ativar o venv não funciona da sempre o mesmo erro:

*activate : O termo 'activate' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet, função, arquivo de script ou programa operável. Verifique a grafia do nome ou, se um caminho
tiver sido incluído, veja se o caminho está correto e tente novamente.*

Porém, quando eu faço o mesmo caminho que faço no PyCharm ( D:\Arquivos\Documents\Python\CursoPython\Guppe\Scripts> activate ) no CMD ele ativa o venv normalmente, até que fica:

*(guppe) D:\Arquivos\Documents\Python\CursoPython\guppe3\Scripts>*

Fui tentar fazer o mesmo procedimento usando o Windows PowerShell e deu o mesmo erro do PyCharm. O que é esse: activate : *O termo 'activate' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet*, tem algo que eu possa fazer para poder trabalhar com o venv pelo powershell?

OBS: eu uso o windows 11

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `.\activate guppe`

Comment: @RobertoBezerra Olá Roberto, se isso respondi a tua pergunta, por favor marque como respondida. Brigadão.

Answer (score 1):

No Windows PowerShell a ativação é feita por script `Activate.ps1` e não por cmdlet:

```
python -m venv venv    
.\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

Comment: @roberto-bezerra Olá Roberto, se isso respondi a tua pergunta, por favor marque como respondida. Brigadão.